# Two path in a graph form a cycle when they have the same starting and ending point

Tags: graph-theory

I have a problem with two path $P$ and $Q$ in a graph with same starting and ending point. How I can show that $P \cup Q$ contain a cycle?
I have also an hint to do this exercise but I don't know how to manage with it.

Hint: consider symmetrical difference on $P$ and $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative hint: do it by induction on the total length.

If $P$ and $Q$ don't intersect (except at their start and end vertices) then they form a cycle. If they do intersect, can you find two shorter paths between some pair of vertices?

Comment: so the total length of $P \cup Q$?

Comment: @AlessandroRecchia I meant length of $P$ plus length of $Q$, but anything similar should work equally well.